# Root element in XML file is not indented

Tags: java, xml, indentation

I have generate an XML file using xmlEventWriter. Why if i open the file with Notepad, the root element is on the same line of the encoding???
        This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><pm xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf/> 
           <dmRefIdent>
                    <dmCode itemLocationCode="A" subSubSystemCode="0" disassyCodeVariant="AA" systemCode="C32" modelIdentCode="26TE" systemDiffCode="A001" infoCodeVariant="A" infoCode="040" assyCode="48" disassyCode="01" subSystemCode="1"></dmCode>
                </dmRefIdent>
```

Comment: Please include the Java code you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a newline between the XML declaration and the document element then you need to put it there yourself before writing the `StartElement` event:

```
writer.add(eventFactory.createSpace("\n"));
```